# How to solve "An error occurred in the application" Application Error in Heroku?

Tags: nodejs-server

[I can't get the data. How to solve the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZYYO.jpg)

Comment: Did you check heroku logs as indicated?

Comment: Kindly share the logs also.